# How to create a dataframe from a simulation list

Tags: r, simulation

Using this code here

```
set.seed(0)
simulations <- vector("list", length = 5000)
simulations <- lapply(1:5000, function(.) waiting_guests(lambda = 10, guests = 12, hours = 8))
```

How do I create a dataframe from a list, where the column title is hour1, hour2, hour3....hour8 and each row is the number of days(5000 in total)?
Also here is the previous code for more information:

```
set.seed(0)
waiting_guests <- function(lambda, guests, hours) {
   vec <- c()
   current_guests <- 0
   remaining_guests <- 0
   # while loop with condition hours != 0                                     
   while (hours != 0) {
      # update values
      current_guests <- remaining_guests + rpois(1, lambda)
      remaining_guests <- max( current_guests - guests, 0)
         vec <- c(vec, remaining_guests)
      #update hours
      hours <- hours-1;
   }
   # return the vector
   return (vec)
}

answer <- waiting_guests(10,12,8) 
print(answer)
```

```
[1] 1 0 2 4 3 5 5 4
```

Where setting the seed keeps the number of waiting_guests the same after each hour each time it is run.

I've tried creating a dataframe like this:

```
dataFrame <- as.data.frame(simulations, col.names=c("hour 1","hour 2","hour 3","hour 4", "hour 5","hour 6","hour 7", "hour 8"))
dataFrame
```

But the number of guests in each is listed vertically, but I want it it be horizontally across the dataframe where hour 1 to 8 are the titles.

Comment: check out the ggplot2 package

Comment: This is different as it is a list not a dataframe which I'm used to

Comment: Is this what you are trying to get? `barplot(table(answer))`

Comment: no on the x axis there needs to be 8  hours and y axis there needs to be 'number of guests waiting" which increases cumulatively

Comment: Hi I've adjusted the question because of the need to convert the list into a dataframe

Comment: How about `barplot(cumsum(answer), names.arg=1:8, xlab="Hours", ylab="Number of Guests Waiting", ylim=c(0, 25))`?

Comment: Hi, I've adjusted the question.

Answer (score 0):

First combine the rows and then convert to a data frame:

```
answer <- do.call(rbind, simulations)
answer <- data.frame(answer)
colnames(answer) <- paste0("hour", 1:8)
day <- as.integer(rownames(answer))
answer <- data.frame(day, answer)
str(answer)
#  'data.frame':    5000 obs. of  9 variables:
#  $ day  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ hour1: num  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 ...
#  $ hour2: num  0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
#  $ hour3: num  2 1 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 ...
#  $ hour4: num  4 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
#  $ hour5: num  3 0 0 0 3 0 0 4 0 0 ...
#  $ hour6: num  5 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 1 ...
#  $ hour7: num  5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
#  $ hour8: num  4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 ...
head(answer)
#   day hour1 hour2 hour3 hour4 hour5 hour6 hour7 hour8
# 1   1     1     0     2     4     3     5     5     4
# 2   2     0     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
# 3   3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
# 4   4     0     0     0     2     0     0     0     0
# 5   5     1     0     1     0     3     2     0     0
# 6   6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Not sure what you mean. The original answer had 8 columns labeled hour1 -- hour8 with 5000 rows as shown by the structure of data frame. I've added the day number and inserted it at the beginning.

Comment: no I want hour1 to hour 8 as column titles, plus a ninth column called day, listing from 1 to 5000.

Comment: See the amended answer. The original answer had 8 columns and 5000 rows with the columns labeled as you requested. This answer adds day at the beginning.